# Solving 1st ODE using Matlab dsolve, having intial condition y(0)=0 and find solution at a t=1

Tags: matlab, ode, dsolve

```
f(t,y)=3y
```

Intial Condition `y(t)=0` when `t=0`
What is the solution when `t=1`

I dont want to solve it numercially, rather somthing like symbolic function.
I am not able to include a way to find `y(t)` when `t=1`

```
syms y(t);
ode= diff(y,t) == 3*y;
    cond= y(0) == 0;
    ySol(t) = dsolve(ode,cond);
    fplot(ySol)
```

I have solved this function numerically and need to compare it with the real solution this I am trying to find a method of doing this on Matlab

Comment: @NickyMattsson How embarrassing. You're absolutely right. I blame it on the early morning... :)

Answer (score 0):

doing this

```
syms y(t);
ode= diff(y,t) == 3*y;
cond= y(0) == 0;
ySol = dsolve(ode,cond)
```

you should get something like:
ySol=0

to evaluate your symbolic expression use [subs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html?searchHighlight=subs&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)

`subs(ySol, t, 1)`

should return 0

and `double(subs(ySol, t, 1))`

should return `0.0`

Comment: and use `double()` to make it a number if needed.

Comment: Eeh, no? the solution to y' = 3y is not exp(3t)-1, y'=3*exp(3t), whereas 3*y = 3exp(3t) - 3. The general solution is Cexp(3t) which for y(0)=0 gives y(t)=0. Which is also what `dsolve` returns

Comment: You are absolutely right @NickyMattsson. I did not test with matlab prior posting. OP misguided me saying a needed the eval of the solution at t=1 I wanted the solution to be a bit more complex than 0....

Comment: @NPE understandable, I was also confused.